# How to correctly apply LDA following PCA?

Tags: classification, pca, dimensionality-reduction, discriminant-analysis

I have a high dimensional dataset ($n \times p$: $30 \times  100$) which I want to use as an testing dataset to build a two group classifier (LDA or QDA). I've read that you can do PCA to do an dimension reduction of your dataset to select to most important features. But I'm a bit confused what you use exactly as the input to build the classifier. I'm familiar with PCA using SVD and what it means.

Consider following situation:

- I do a SVD of my dataset.
- I look at the scores of the first couple of principal components.
- When I assign my scores a label indicating from which group they come, I see that the 3th PC best separates my 2 groups (although it only explains 7% of the total variance).

What do I do next?

1. I take the 3th PC transform to the original parameter space (scores * loadings * scale + mean) and build my classifier
2. I look at the loadings in the 3th PC and try to decide which parameters in my original parameter space are important and build a classifier only using these.
3. ...

Option 2 seems the most sensible in my opinion but I'm not entirely sure. 
Also If I see that only the 3th PC is important to explain the variance in my two groups, can I forget about the first two PC in my further analysis?

Comment: It is unclear whether you want just dimensionality reduction (given that you have n<p) or you want feature selection (i.e. you insist to stay only with very few variables out of 100 _before_ you proceed to LDA).

Comment: If your wish is the first one I said about, i.e. only the fact that n<p bothers you and only this fact forces you to apply PCA, - then you should retain 28 (all but one last) components in PCA and do LDA on those 28 components, leaving there few strongest discrimimants. Each of those is the linear combination of 28 components, each of which is in turn the linear combination of 100 variables.

Comment: See also: [Best practice for dimensionality reduction with PCA and LDA: does it make sense to combine them?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/106121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to do LDA after PCA I would keep the first k components. Don't try and figure out which of the components are important and don't go back to the original parameter space. You can feed in the k dimensional data into your LDA classifier and let it figure out what is important there.

Comment: You mean use the principal components to build your classifier? How is this possible? How can  your classifier know to look at the correct parameters without when you give it test data (which has all p parameters) without the information in your loadings. Or do you have to transform somehow your test data and your future data?

Comment: You always do the exact same transformations to your test data as you did to your training data.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. So the following should be the right thing to do with the test data afterwards. (test_data-mean_training) * scale_training * q loadings_train

Comment: Looks cgood to me.

Comment: If you want to feed only scores into the LDA training that actually have discriminativ power, consider using e.g. PLS instead of PCA for the dimensionality reduction step.